Using showColumnMenuAfterMouseClick to show context menu on column header disappears after appearing in v31
We have an icon in grid column header(custom header template), on clicking of the icon we call GridApi method "showColumnMenuAfterMouseClick" to show the context menu. It was working fine till v30 but after upgrading to v31, the context menu appears but disappears immediately. I have used event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() but no luck.
Can someone help me with this.? Is this is an issue with new version or I should do it differently.?
